# "No module named tensorflow" error after installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

After installing the TensorFlow CPU version with virtualenv (in Ubuntu 14.0), when I try to test the installation with Python (not from the source directory), I get the following error:

> No module named tensorflow

Any explanation?

I am following the exact sequence of steps from the TensorFlow installation page.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>>
```

Comment: show `pip freeze` please, and please check that you are using appropriate virtualenv

Comment: How did you install tensorflow? This is not enough information to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Tensoflow works only with Python 3.5.x version

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow does work with python 2.7 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip. Just wanted to add it here so no one get it wrong. Cant comment since I don't have the reputation yet :(

Check your env and pip to make sure you have installed it for the correct python version in the env.